# Jasmine: Why toBeUndefined and not.toBeDefined?

Tags: jasmine

I'm just learning the Jasmine library, and I've noticed that Jasmine has a very limited number of built-in assertions.  I've also noticed that, despite having such a limited number, two of its assertions appear to be redundant: `toBeDefined`/`toBeUndefined`.

In other words, both of these would seem to check for the same exact thing:

```
expect(1).toBeDefined();
expect(undefined).not.toBeUndefined();
```

Is there some reason for this, like a case where `toBeDefined` isn't the same as `toBeUndefined`?  Or is this just the one assertion in Jasmine that has two perfectly equal ways of being invoked?

Comment: "toBe... or not.toBe..." - that is the question. I'm here all week folks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One might assume the same for `toBeTruthy` and `toBeFalsy`, or `toBeLessThan` and `toBeGreaterThan` (although I guess the missing assert from the last two is `toEqual`). In the end it comes down to readability and user preference.

To give you a more complete answer, it might be useful to take a look at the code that is invoked for these functions. The code that is executed goes through separate paths (so `toBeUndefined` is not simply `!toBeDefined`). The only real answer that makes sense is readability (or giving in to annoying feature requests). https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/tree/main/src/core/matchers

Comment: Broken link.
Actual link (on 22/06/2021): https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/tree/main/src/core/matchers